# Loading a picture using AS3 issues

Tags: image, actionscript-3, loader

I am trying to upload a picture when a user clicks on a button using AS3. I have a button and a progress bar on the stage. This is the relevant code:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

myPB.source = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo;

btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnImage);

function btnImage(event:MouseEvent):void{
   myLoader.load(new URLRequest("MyPic.jpeg"));
   addCild(myPB);
   removeChild(myPB);
   btn_one = null;

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishImage);
     function finishImage(event:Event):void{
      addChild(myLoader);
      removeChild(myLoader);
      btn_one = null;
```

When I execute the code this error appears  Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found
Any ideas were I am going wrong?

Comment: check image' path, may be it is "MyPic.jpg" and not "MyPic.jpeg"

Comment: it is nor related but for the tip , add event listeners before call load..

Comment: i think your error comes from "myPB.source = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo;" not from your loader. Is the error thrown on click or on init?

Comment: Upload a picture from Flash Player or Adobe Air? Local or on server?

Comment: Have you tried the full path? in the urlrequest ('http://..../.../image.jpeg')

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply's. Cherniv and DJ I did has you both suggested but I keep getting the same error from before. I am attempting to upload a picture using Flash Player locally. The error comes from when I click on a button then that annoying error message appears in my output. I'm stuck! I have been tweaking around with my code but to no avail. Love to know how I can fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

//myPB.source = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo;

btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnImage);

function btnImage(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishImage);
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("MyPic.jpeg"));
    //addCild(myPB);
    //removeChild(myPB);
   btn_one = null;
}

function finishImage(event:Event):void{
    addChild(myLoader);
    //removeChild(myLoader);
    btn_one = null;
}
```

This should work. I don't know what you try to accomplish with adding a Child and removing the same child directly afterwards.

Hope this helps